# Control the order the tables have been created in jpa

Tags: mysql, jpa

Does it exist a way to control the order in which the tables have been created by the persistence provider? I got this  mysql 1146 error. I suppose it happens because it try to create an entity that needs for reservation table but it doesn't found it so this cause the following exception. Does exist a way to fix that?

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'volaconnoi_db.reservation' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESERVATION_ROUTE_ID_ROUTE FOREIGN KEY (ROUTE_ID_ROUTE) REFERENCES ROUTE (ID_ROUTE)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESERVATION_ROUTE_ID_ROUTE FOREIGN KEY (ROUTE_ID_ROUTE) REFERENCES ROUTE (ID_ROUTE)")
```

This is the USER_CREDENTIAL entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_CREDENTIAL")
@SecondaryTable(name = "CLIENT", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USERNAME"))
public class UserCredential implements Serializable
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String group_name;

    private Date create_date;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String zip_code;
    private String country;
    private int fidelity_points;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    private List<Reservation> reservationsList;

    public UserCredential()
    {

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "GROUP_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getGroup_name()
    {
        return group_name;
    }

    public void setGroup_name(String group_name)
    {
        this.group_name = group_name;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreate_date()
    {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(Date create_date)
    {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }



    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable= false, table="CLIENT")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "SURNAME", nullable= false, table = "CLIENT")
    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname)
    {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", nullable= false , table = "CLIENT")
    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "CITY", nullable = false, table = "CLIENT")
    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE", nullable = false, table = "CLIENT")
    public String getZip_code()
    {
        return zip_code;
    }

    public void setZip_code(String zip_code)
    {
        this.zip_code = zip_code;
    }

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY", nullable = false, table = "CLIENT")
    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIDELITY_POINTS", nullable = false, table = "CLIENT")
    public int getFidelity_points()
    {
        return fidelity_points;
    }

    public void setFidelity_points(int fidelity_points)
    {
        this.fidelity_points = fidelity_points;
    }

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME"))
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers()
    {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers (List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers)
    {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "username", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Reservation> getReservationsList()
    {
        return reservationsList;
    }

    public void setReservationsList(List<Reservation> reservationsList)
    {
        this.reservationsList = reservationsList;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the username fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof UserCredential))
        {
            return false;
        }
        UserCredential other = (UserCredential) object;
        if ((this.username == null && other.username != null) || (this.username != null && !this.username.equals(other.username)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "it.volaconoi.entity.UserCredential[ id=" + username + " ]";
    }

}
```

THIS IS THE ROUTE ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTE")

public class Route implements Serializable
{
    private String id_route;  
    private String airlane;  
    private String aircraft_id;
    private Airport airport_city_source;   
    private Airport airport_city_dest; 
    private Date departure_date;  
    private Date arrival_date;   
    private String travel_class;
    private int seats;
    private float price;

    private List<Reservation> reservationsList;

    public Route()
    {    
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void setIdRoute()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYYHHmm");

        String format_departure_date = sdf.format(this.getDeparture_date());

        String unique_id_route = this.getAirlane() +
                                 this.getAircraft_id() + 
                                 this.getAirport_city_source().getCity() +
                                 this.getAirport_city_dest().getCity() +
                                 format_departure_date;

        this.setId_route(unique_id_route.replaceAll(" ", ""));
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ROUTE")
    public String getId_route()
    {
        return id_route;
    }

    public void setId_route(String id_route)
    {
        this.id_route = id_route;
    }

    @Column(name = "AIRLANE", nullable = false)
    public String getAirlane()
    {
        return airlane;
    }

    public void setAirlane(String airlane)
    {
        this.airlane = airlane;
    }

    @Column(name = "AIRCRAFT_ID", nullable = false)
    public String getAircraft_id()
    {
        return aircraft_id;
    }

    public void setAircraft_id(String aircraft_id)
    {
        this.aircraft_id = aircraft_id;
    }

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    public Airport getAirport_city_source()
    {
        return airport_city_source;
    }

    public void setAirport_city_source(Airport airport_city_source)
    {
        this.airport_city_source = airport_city_source;
    }

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    public Airport getAirport_city_dest()
    {
        return airport_city_dest;
    }

    public void setAirport_city_dest(Airport airport_city_dest)
    {
        this.airport_city_dest = airport_city_dest;
    }

    @Column(name = "DEPARTURE_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDeparture_date()
    {

        return this.departure_date;
    }

    public void setDeparture_date(Date departure_date)
    {
        this.departure_date = departure_date;
    }

    @Column(name = "ARRIVAL_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getArrival_date()
    {
        return arrival_date;
    }

    public void setArrival_date(Date arrival_date)
    {
        this.arrival_date = arrival_date;
    }

    @Column(name = "TRAVEL_CLASS", nullable = false)
    public String getTravel_class()
    {
        return travel_class;
    }

    public void setTravel_class(String travel_class)
    {
        this.travel_class = travel_class;
    }

    @Column(name = "SEATS", nullable = false)
    public int getSeats()
    {
        return seats;
    }

    public void setSeats(int seats)
    {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    public float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Reservation> getReservationsList()
    {
        return reservationsList;
    }

    public void setReservationsList(List<Reservation> reservationsList)
    {
        this.reservationsList = reservationsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id_route != null ? id_route.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id_route fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Route))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Route other = (Route) object;
        if ((this.id_route == null && other.id_route != null) || (this.id_route != null && !this.id_route.equals(other.id_route)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "it.volaconoi.entity.Route[ id=" + id_route + " ]";
    }    
}
```

This is the RESERVATION entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESERVATION")
public class Reservation implements Serializable
{
    private String id;
    private int passengers;
    private int luggages;
    private float price;
    private Date date_reservation;
    private boolean cancelled;

    private UserCredential username;

    private Route route;

    public Reservation()
    {  

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_RESERVATION")
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSENGERS", nullable = false)
    public int getPassengers()
    {
        return passengers;
    }

    public void setPassengers(int passengers)
    {
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }

    @Column(name = "LUGGAGES", nullable = false)
    public int getLuggages()
    {
        return luggages;
    }

    public void setLuggages(int luggages)
    {
        this.luggages = luggages;
    }

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    public float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATE_PLACED", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDate_reservation()
    {
        return date_reservation;
    }

    public void setDate_reservation(Date date_reservation)
    {
        this.date_reservation = date_reservation;
    }

    @Column(name = "CANCELLED", nullable = false)
    public boolean isCancelled()
    {
        return cancelled;
    }

    public void setCancelled(boolean cancelled)
    {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    public UserCredential getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(UserCredential username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROUTE", nullable = false)
    public Route getRoute()
    {
        return route;
    }

    public void setRoute(Route route)
    {
        this.route = route;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Reservation))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Reservation other = (Reservation) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "it.volaconoi.entity.Reservation[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

As you may see these three entities are related to each one

Comment: No one know how to fix the issue? Any idea... I'm stucked here since two days...

Comment: I don't think anyone can tell you the problem without more information, and I don't think it has to do with ordering - turn on logging to Finest and see what is issued.  It is likely that an attempt to create the RESERVATION table failed before your JPA provider issued an alter table statement on it, so you need to find out why.  Try naming your question to match the actual problem you are trying to resolve to get it more attention, as ordering tables in JPA might not gather much in the way of responses - and I'm not sure that it would really help anyway.

Comment: I know the reason why it doesn't work...it is really simple...jpa sucks and it is the truth

Comment: the problem is I don't know what more informations I share...

Comment: "JPA sucks" ? JPA is a spec. There are many implementations. You use one, and have some problem in some specific feature. There are many other implementations. What information to share? how about the classes, the metadata, the log? Throwing your toys out of the pram and blaming "JPA" is hardly a way to encourage constructive comment

Comment: I could try to post the entity but I'm pretty sure it will be really difficult to find out the problem...

Comment: @NeilStockton: JPA is a spec which I use all the time, but in some ways it does suck. :) Can't add indexes to `MappedSuperClass`? Sucks. And don't get me started on the implementations because they suck much worse, at least as far as schema creation is concerned. It's practically useless because each implementation does things differently and none do things 100% correctly.

Comment: @NeilStockton: I often have to use one implementation for schema generation and a different implementation when actually running just to get the least sucky combination.

Comment: @Mazzy: This is nit-picky, but in your `toString` methods use `getClass().getName()` instead of hard-wiring the class name to survive any future refactoring, or child classes.

Comment: In order to fix the problem what do you suggest? I have changed the database but the problem is always the same

Comment: For you the relationship are correct?

Comment: @Mazzy: Don't rush me!  :P  I don't see any issues so far, though. In the mean time, you could try using another implementation when generating the tables to see if that helps (swapping EclipseLink for Hibernate or vice versa).

Comment: Do you suggest to use hibernate? Good idea... I'm going to install it. Let's see stay tuned

Comment: No idea why some idiot voted this down, so voting up to compensate. **TO ALL:** If you vote something down without an explanation, you're an idiot. No doubts about it, first-class, grade-A moron.

Comment: @Mazzy: This may or may not fix the issue, but upgrade to at least version 2.5.1. Version 2.5.0 had bugs which prevented the modelgen stuff from working properly. At least use 2.5.1 when compiling (should be compatible).

Comment: @Mazzy: I've reproduced the error. See my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56004/discussion-between-alvin-thompson-and-mazzy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an error so fixing this may make your problem go away. Then again this may be unrelated:

In `Reservation`, the type of `id` is `String`, but in `getId()` you specify `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. AFAIK MySQL doesn't support auto generation of string IDs but only integer IDs. Remove this and see if things work.

**UPDATE:**

I've reproduced the error on my machine, and this is indeed the problem. If you check your output you will find a warning (not an error) similar to:

> [EL Warning]: 2014-06-20
>   15:47:46.224--ServerSession(1565614310)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Incorrect column specifier for column 'ID' Error Code: 1063 Call:
>   CREATE TABLE NEWENTITY (ID VARCHAR(255) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME
>   VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID)) Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE
>   TABLE NEWENTITY (ID VARCHAR(255) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME
>   VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))")

I imagine you missed it because it's a warning and not an error. I also imagine this gets output as a warning and not an error because sometimes an error creating the table is not an issue (for example, if the table already exists). EclipseLink apparently isn't smart enough to handle cases where there is a true error, so it outputs as a warning (see "JPA sucks", above).

The EclipseLink/MySQL combination does **not** support a generation type of `IDENTITY` for String IDs. `IDENTITY` means that it's up to the database (and not the JPA implementation provider) to create the ID. MySQL only supports creating integer IDs so the column type must be integer if you use `AUTO INCREMENT` (see the generated code).

If you really want your IDs to be a String but also automatically generate an ID, then use a generation type of `AUTO`. `AUTO` means the JPA implementation provider will handle creating the IDs; EclipseLink will use a sequence table and will handle converting the values there to a String for you.

Comment: Another idiot. If you vote down, give an explanation so I can tell you why you're wrong (and you are). This answer fits the error the asker is getting because if there was an earlier error preventing the table from being created, obviously the foreign key won't be created, and the error will match the error given. I hope you realize that even though the user can't see who down voted, down votes are **not** anonymous and you could face action if it was determined you had no legitimate reason to do it.

Comment: Thank thank thank thank and thank you !!! You have fixed my issue...everything now it works...

Comment: I'm really unlucky...the problems are here again... but now is different

Comment: @Mazzy: Depending on what it is, it is likely a new issue so a new question may be appropriate.

Comment: please continue this discussion in chat

Comment: @Mazzy: did you find the issue?

Comment: No I'm driving crazy...I hate I hate I hate Glassfish and JPA

Comment: @Mazzy: I assume `PhoneNumber` is an Entity and not an Embeddable, so you can't use `ElementCollection` with it. The easiest fix is (in `UserCredential`) removing the current annotations on `getPhoneNumbers` and adding the annotation `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "PhoneNumber")`.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem...before today everything works...I have always used Embeddable

Comment: @Mazzy: Whoops. add a `user` field to PhoneNumber (type UserCredential), then `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")

Comment: Is PhoneNumber an Embeddable? if not, that's a problem if not **this** problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56006/discussion-between-mazzy-and-alvin-thompson).

Comment: If you want to use a join table, simply use `@ManyToMany` instead.